# Control sub line color in tkz-euclide grid

Tags: tikz-pgf, tkz-euclide

I am interested in using a third color in this grid for the "sub" lines. Is this possible?

```
\documentclass[twoside,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[hmargin=0.75in,vmargin=0.5in,includeheadfoot,headheight=10mm,headsep=4mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor} \definecolor{Color1}{HTML}{990000} \definecolor{Color2}{HTML}{009900} \definecolor{Color3}{HTML}{000099}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\def\tkzRatioLineGrid{0.5} 
\tkzInit[xmax=40, ymax=50, xmin=-40, ymin=-50, xstep=5, ystep=5]
\tkzGrid[color=Color2, line width=0.4mm, sub, subxstep=1, subystep=1]
\tkzAxeXY[line width=0.6mm, color=Color1]
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\clearpage
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Subcolor for sub lines is defined as a fraction from color of grid lines, in the file `tkz-tools-base` we can find

```
\pgfkeys{
  /tkzGrid/.cd,
  color/.code      = {\def\tkz@gd@color{#1}%
                      \edef\tkz@gd@subcolor{%
                      \tkz@gd@color!\tkzCoeffSubColor}}}
```

We can add key `subcolor` for `tkzGrid` like this

```
\pgfkeys{/tkzGrid/.cd,subcolor/.code={\def\tkz@gd@subcolor{#1}}}
```

In this case just add your color with `subcolor=Color3`

**Code**

```
\documentclass[twoside,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[hmargin=0.75in,vmargin=0.5in,includeheadfoot,headheight=10mm,headsep=4mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor} \definecolor{Color1}{HTML}{990000} \definecolor{Color2}{HTML}{009900} \definecolor{Color3}{HTML}{000099}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}

\makeatletter
\pgfkeys{/tkzGrid/.cd,subcolor/.code={\def\tkz@gd@subcolor{#1}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\def\tkzRatioLineGrid{0.5} 
\tkzInit[xmax=40, ymax=50, xmin=-40, ymin=-50, xstep=5, ystep=5]
\tkzGrid[color=Color2, line width=0.4mm, sub, subxstep=1, subystep=1,subcolor=Color3]
\tkzAxeXY[line width=0.6mm, color=Color1]
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\clearpage
\end{document}
```